# Does the package cached_network_image reduce the amount of network bandwidth from Firestore Storage?

Tags: image, firebase, flutter, caching, google-cloud-storage

Currently I am reading an image URL from a firebase document that contains an Image URL from Firebase Cloud Storage, and then using the package [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)  to load the images to the user.

My question is, does using `cached_network_image` for loading images reduce the networking bandwidth since many images will be loaded from the cache and not the url? If not, then how would one achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cached_network_image` is using a cache mechanism which will check if there is a file available for the url you're providing, will use the cached version so it will definitely reduces your network usage. Here is a function from `DefaultCacheManager` class in `cache_manager.dart` in Flutter`s SDK:

```
Future<void> _pushFileToStream(StreamController streamController, String url,
Map<String, String> headers, bool withProgress) async {
  FileInfo cacheFile;
  try {
    cacheFile = await getFileFromCache(url);
    if (cacheFile != null) {
      streamController.add(cacheFile);
      withProgress = false;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(
        'CacheManager: Failed to load cached file for $url with error:\n$e');
  }
  if (cacheFile == null || cacheFile.validTill.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
    try {
      await for (var response
          in _webHelper.downloadFile(url, authHeaders: headers)) {
        if (response is DownloadProgress && withProgress) {
          streamController.add(response);
        }
        if (response is FileInfo) {
          streamController.add(response);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      assert(() {
        print(
            'CacheManager: Failed to download file from $url with error:\n$e');
        return true;
      }());
      if (cacheFile == null && streamController.hasListener) {
        streamController.addError(e);
      }
    }
  }
  unawaited(streamController.close());
}
```

As you can see if it can find the cached file using the url you're providing and the file is valid, it will use that instead of downloading.

Comment: Thanks, so from what I understand ' cached_network_image ' will not be able to know if the content of the URL has changed, rather will sill use the old version that was cached, right?

Comment: Yes I think that's the case @MK